# Each Do loop, check if item is the last one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following loop

```
<% @museum.museumcloseddays.order(:closedday).each do |day| %>
      <%= day.closedday.strftime("%B") + " " + day.closedday.day.to_s  %>
<% end %>
```

Which writes the month and day of a venue closed day.

I would try to separates them with a comma, and if the |day| item is the last item in the each loop, writes a period.

Then I try to test the |day| item using the method last as follows:

```
if day.last then ...
```

but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Array::select and Array::join. A completely simplistic example is:

```
["a", "b", "c"].select { |i| "#{a}!" }.join(',') + '.'
```

This replaces your entire each loop and you'd put the transformation of your output in the select block. Select will create an array of your output strings and join will delimit them with a comma, not putting one at the end.

Here is my attempt to put it in terms of your example:

```
<%= 
  @museum.museumcloseddays.order(:closedday).select do |day|
    day.closedday.strftime("%B") + " " + day.closedday.day.to_s
  end.join(',') + '.'
%>
```

I'm not entirely sure I have the details of that solution correct because I don't have your sandbox to play in but I know that the approach of select then join will do what you want to do with out any addition check on position of your 'day' in the array.

Comment: Many thanks @jaydel . Not sure why but I got something funny : #<Museumclosedday:0x8f46b88>,#<Museumclosedday:0x8f46a20>. But I pushed the days within a new array : `@days.push(day.closedday.strftime("%B") + " " + day.closedday.day.to_s) `. And then adding the following after the loop: `@days = @days.join(', ') + '.'` which works perfectly.

Comment: it's possible that you'd need to string interpolate that middle line. I'm not sure--I don't have enough context to actually run and test it. Select should result in an Array of String objects.

Comment: `"#{day.closedday.strftime('%B')} #{day.closedday.day.to_s}"`

Comment: I used each instead of select. But I will try again with select and your new bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `.each_with_index` and print comma if its not the last element e.g. `index != size_of_museumclosedays`

or print comma if `museumclosedays[-1] != day`